# How do I create an attribute-based access control in my smart contract to control user access and permissions?

Tags: solidity, ethereum-classic

For my Master's thesis, I am trying to create a decentralized file storage system using ethereum, solidity and ipfs. I want to code the smart contract with attribute-based access control but do not have much knowledge on this. Most of the links I have seen so far are of role-based access control. 
Could someone please guide me with a few links or a simple code explanation?

Answer (score 2):

Attribute-Based Access Control (ABAC) is all about the attributes (or characteristics) of a user. For e.g., you may only allow users owning 100+ tokens to vote to decide whether an ERC-20 based token should be migrated to its own blockchain. Other attributes could be external data like IP address (or its geo-location) used to issue a transaction (as verified by an oracle), user category (as specified in a registry contract), or off-chain secret (proved using a hash or zero-knowledge proof).

What matter is you specify how these attributes should be validated within your smart contract. For e.g. Ether balance can be checked like,

```
if (address.balance >= 100){
    can_vote = true;
}
```

If it's ERC-20 use `balanceOf(account) >= 100`

A simple, but more detailed example is available at https://blockgeeks.com/introduction-to-solidity-acl-and-events-part-2/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

**A library:**

```
library Roles {
    enum Flag {
        Role1,
        Role2,
        Role3
    }

    function isAuthorizedToRole1(uint256 _flags) internal pure returns (bool) {return isAuthorized(_flags, Flag.Role1);}
    function isAuthorizedToRole2(uint256 _flags) internal pure returns (bool) {return isAuthorized(_flags, Flag.Role2);}
    function isAuthorizedToRole3(uint256 _flags) internal pure returns (bool) {return isAuthorized(_flags, Flag.Role3);}
    function isAuthorized(uint256 _flags, Flag _flag) private pure returns (bool) {return ((_flags >> uint256(_flag)) & 1) == 1;}
}
```

**A contract:**

```
contract Users {
    address public owner;
    mapping(address => uint256) public roles;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function getRole(address _user) external view returns (uint256) {
        return roles[_user];
    }

    function setRole(address _user, uint256 _role) external {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "illegal caller");
        roles[_user] = _role;
    }
}
```

Then, any other contract can utilize the above in order to manage access-control; for example:

```
contract Manager {
    using Roles for uint256;

    Users public users;

    constructor(Users _users) public {
        users = _users;
    }

    function isAuthorizedToRole1(address _user) external view returns (bool) {
        return users.getRole(_user).isAuthorizedToRole1();
    }

    function isAuthorizedToRole2(address _user) external view returns (bool) {
        return users.getRole(_user).isAuthorizedToRole2();
    }

    function isAuthorizedToRole3(address _user) external view returns (bool) {
        return users.getRole(_user).isAuthorizedToRole3();
    }
}
```